# DirectShow capture devices disappear while connected with Remote Desktop

Tags: directshow, remote-desktop

I use an excellent videosurveillance Windows app named Blue Iris that saves audio/video from 4 USB webcams + 1 IP cam.
All the 5 cams have integrated microphones.
For the IP cam, the app receives and saves audio via IP camera stream.
For the 4 USB webcams, Blue Iris receives and saves audio via "DirectShow".

Connecting to this PC via Remote Desktop (RDP8) works wonderfully with 15-30fps full color videos but there's a problem: while I'm connected all the DirectShow capture devices DISAPPEAR (supposedly replaced by the remote virtual audio device) and therefore no audio can be listened nor saved for these USB webcams.

I tried all the play/recording settings combinations on the RDP client without being able to keep those DirectShow capture devices.
Do you know a solution to keep them?

Here http://www13.picfront.org/token/iJrU/2012/12/22/2121473.jpg  is a screenshot that shows the 2 situations: while RDP now connected and while RDP connected.

Note: TeamViewer doesn't have this problem but it shows only 1-3 fps :(   so I use RDP8 because it's 10x better!

Comment: Is it a programming Q? Screenshot link is broken.

Answer (score 1):

In the remote desktop client, change the audio settings to "Leave at remote computer" before connecting.

If you want to change it on the server, clear the audio redirection in the [client settings](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770631%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)